# Stepper Motors not responding, Ender 5, BTT SKR1.4, tmc2130

Tags: creality-ender-5, stepper, motor, skr-v1.4, tmc2130

I upgraded my ender 5's main board to a BTT SKR 1.4 Turbo and am using the TMC2130 (V3) drivers. None of my stepper motors are responding

I'm having quite a hard time figuring out why the steppers won't move. If I run M122, the spi connection is good and the motors are enabled with the right settings. Then as soon as I send a move command, nothing happens to the motor, but the M122 command shows that it is now disabled.

Tried a whole bunch of firmware combinations (Marlin 2.1). I've adjusted the current, disabled hybrid mode, disabled the stealth option, and about every option that anyone online suggested might be an issue.

adjusted the vref on the driver and tried every combination of stepper wiring.

Tomorrow I'm going to try building an Arduino project to drive the motors with the stepper. That will at least verify the driver isn't broken and the motor wiring is correct.

I'm pretty stumped.... I reached out to BTT for support, but I've heard their support is pretty awful, which I hope to be false.

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I've missed any critical details. This is my first time posting in the 3d print stack exchange.